EMI shields: When to use 2-piece cap+frame, just a frame, or just a shield (or just a cap)?
We are looking at an EMI shield for an LNA and this is the first time that I have worked with surface mount shielding. This EMI shielding part comes in either a two-part "cap" and "frame," or a one-part "shield":
"Frame" (5mm tall)

"Cap" (3mm tall)

"Shield" (5mm tall)

Questions:

Why is the frame covered with the circle-strap thing across the top?

if you are going to use a cap anyway, what is the point of the circle thing?


Given that the holes are way smaller than the wavelength of the frequencies we care about, do you even need a cap, or is a frame sufficient?
I have noticed that some parts are more available than others. For example, the frames are often available in high volume, but the caps are less common and sometimes the capless shields for the same size are not even available.  I realize that some of this is market demand, but are there practical consideration as well?

For example, can a "cap" be used as a 1-piece shield if the 3mm clearance is sufficient?





if you are going to use a cap anyway, what is the point of the circle
thing?

Probably a point for the SMT machine to pick up, seeing how it comes in a tray and is SMD-able.

Given that the holes are way smaller than the wavelength of the
frequencies we care about, do you even need a cap, or is a frame
sufficient?

Probably the best way to determine this is by testing, because you can have harmonics that can have higher frequency content. If you are doing FCC testing and you have the time, leave it off for a test and see if you still pass. If you do then leave it off of the product BOM.

For example, can a "cap" be used as a 1-piece shield if the 3mm clearance is sufficient?

Usually the RF shields have tabs on the bottom to help adhere to solder, the cap may not. This isn't apparent on the datasheet so you'll have to look at the parts or ask the manufacturer.

Indeed, note that the frame has slots, making a folded dipole geometry: therefore it passes frequencies in bands resonant to that structure. The openings also pass some electric field even at DC; whether this gives sufficient attenuation, you'll have to model or test.
